# 言ってるみたいに+conditional

Tags: grammar, meaning, parsing

> アニメについての感謝イラストを描いたんだけど、**暗に「サイタマのイメージが違う」と不満言ってるみたいに取られたら嫌だなと思ってボツにした奴。**  考え過ぎかな。  でも描き直します。

I was reading this tweet and did not understand the bold part.
My translation would be:

> Regarding the illustration gift for the anime I drew them but, as if complaining implicitly that "the image of Saitama is different" if someone received they would turn it down.
>     Maybe I am thinking too much.
>    Anyway let's draw it back

Edit:
My new translation would be:

> Regarding the illustration gifts for the anime I drew them but, implicit they looked liked they were complaining that "Saitama's image is different" so if I got one I would not be very happy.
>   Thinking this I rejected those one.
>    Maybe I am thinking too much but I'll redraw them.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to have gotten some words wrong.

- ボツにする: *to give up on*, *to throw away* in this context, because he didn't even show it to someone before
- 奴【やつ】: (slangy) *the thing*, *that of*.

  - ボツにした奴 in this context refers to not "the person who turned down my illustration" but "the illustration I gave up on".
- 取る: *to interpret*, *to understand as*, *to take* (as in "take it seriously"). See [definition 10 here](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/161480/meaning/m0u/).
- ～したら嫌だ: *to hate it if ～*, *to feel bad about ～*

> 『暗に「サイタマのイメージが違う」と不満言ってるみたいに取られたら嫌だな』と思って、ボツにした奴

Literally: The thing I threw away, thinking "I hate it if the illustration were interpreted as if I were implicitly complaining 'Saitama's image is different/wrong' ".

Although he, the author of the manga version, probably drew [this illustration](https://twitter.com/NEBU_KURO/status/676692618844045312) purely as a joke, it turned out that the the illustration somehow looked like a complaint against the anime staff. So he gave up directly presenting it to the anime staff. Instead, he posted it as a tweet.

Comment: ボツにした奴 was referring to the thing he drew, that I got right but not the meaning of 取る. Is this indirect passive or passive of damage/nuisance? Could I write something like this?

アニメについての感謝イラストを描いたんだけど、(僕はそれを)暗に「サイタマのイメージが違う」と不満言ってるみたいに取られたら嫌だなと思ってボツにした奴。

I think this way he tries to convey the nuances of the fact that he might be misunderstood.
Is it correct?